# Как получить от пользователя значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Код не принимает в аргумент переменную `а`, то есть спрашивает название, и сразу открывает браузер. Я на тест ставил time.sleep() чтобы успеть ввести название, но получается, что все равно переменная не записывается.

```
def one_user(message):
    a = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи название")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(a, one_user)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("ссылка")
    btn = driver.find_element_by_name("ystext")
    btn.send_keys(a)
    btn.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Тут что происходить вообще должно?

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я понял вы используете pytelegramapi, если да, то bot.send_message ничего не возвращает, поэтому переменная а и не может записаться.

Comment: Можете открыть документацию и увидеть, что sendMessage возвращает объект Message: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage